# Proving $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}$ is algebraic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I prove that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}$ is algebraic?

I have been trying various things, and have failed as of now. I know that the degree of the polynomial satisfying this equation has to be $\leq 6$. But that is all I know. Clearly, the simple idea of building the polynomial from the root itself, like in the case of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ does not work here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On the contrary, building a polynomial from the root works perfectly!

Comment: It may be more instructive to prove in general that the sum of algebraics is algebraic

Comment: it is enough to show that is is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$...

Answer (score 8):

Let

$$x=\sqrt 2+\sqrt[3] 3$$
then
$$(x-\sqrt 2)^3=x^3-3x^2\sqrt2+6x-2\sqrt 2=3\iff x^3+6x-3=\sqrt2(3x^2+2)$$
now square the two sides
$$(x^3+6x-3)^2=2(3x^2+2)^2$$
and simplify you find that $x$ is a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

If $x=\sqrt 2+\sqrt[3]3$ then $(x-\sqrt 2)^3=3$, i.e. 
$$ x^3-3\sqrt 2 x^2+6x-2\sqrt 2=3$$
or 
$$ x^3+6x -3=(3x^2+2)\sqrt 2.$$
Now square